# How to dynamically change fill attribute based on Shiny input without replotting paths in ggvis

Tags: r, mapping, shiny, ggvis

I am trying to create a map using ggvis that interactively updates the fill attribute based on a Shiny input value. However, I am running into three issues:

1. **Integrating ggvis into Shiny:** For whatever reason, the ggvis will not show up when I run the Shiny app, though outside of Shiny app, it displays just fine. In case it is relevant, I am using RStudio on a Mac running OS Yosemite 10.10.
2. **Changing fill attribute without redrawing paths:** I would like to dynamically change the fill attribute of polygons based on an input value, without re-drawing the paths themselves. This approach is an attempt to reduce running time as I'm mapping 1450 political units and it takes a while to create the base layer.
3. **Changing legend values:** The fills are based on a categorical value that essentially cuts a continuous variable (again, to try to reduce running time). I want to customize the color palette as well, but am having trouble using either the parameters in scale_ordinal or add_legend to change the display values of the legend. Instead of labeling each category, I only want to label a string for the first and last as "Low" and "High" respectively.

For a reproducible code example, please see below. Thanks in advance for helping a Shiny/ggvis newbie!

## server.ui

```
# libraries
suppressMessages(library(dplyr))
suppressMessages(library(ggvis))
library(shiny)
library(RColorBrewer)
# create dummy data
base.long <- c(0, 1, 1, 0)
base.lat <- c(0, 0, 1, 1)
test <- data.frame(long = rep(c(base.long, base.long + 1), 3),
    lat = c(rep(base.lat, 2), rep(base.lat + 1, 2), rep(base.lat + 2, 2)),
    order = rep(1:4, 6), group = rep(seq(1:6), 4)[order(rep(seq(1:6), 4))], 
    var = rep(seq(5, 30, 5), 4)[order(rep(seq(5, 30, 5), 4))])
# define color palette
spectrum <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(n = 4, name="YlGn"))
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    # determine fill color based on variable 
    toplot <- reactive({
        test$fill.col <- as.character(cut(test$var, seq(10, 30, 5), 
        include.lowest = T, labels = spectrum(4)))
        test$fill.col <- ifelse(is.na(test$fill.col) | 
                test$var < input$range[1] | test$var > input$range[2], 
            "#FFFFFF", test$fill.col)
        return(test)
    })
    toplot %>% 
        group_by(group) %>%
        ggvis(x = ~long, y = ~lat) %>%
        layer_paths(fill = ~fill.col) %>%
        scale_ordinal("fill", range = c("#FFFFFF", spectrum(4)),
            label = "Variable Value") %>%
        set_options(width = 400, height = 600, keep_aspect = T) %>%
        bind_shiny("test.ggvis")
})
```

## ui.r

```
suppressMessages(library("ggvis"))
shinyUI(fluidPage(
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                sliderInput("range", label = "Filter Range",
                    min = 5, max = 30, step = 5, value = c(5, 25))
            ),
        mainPanel(ggvisOutput("test.ggvis"))
    )
))
```